# Tiny MCE (jquery plugin version) not showing toolbar in IE (works fine in other browsers)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I had an implementation working well but for some reason IE decided it was tired of playing nice.  I have an advanced implementation of TinyMCE (the jquery plugin version - see http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_23.php for details).

It still works great in all browsers but IE.  In IE it shows the drop-down options for Format, Font family, and Font size, but only as text.. not as a drop down normally looks.  All other buttons on the toolbar are missing.  (I've tried IE8 and IE8 Compatibility Mode)

I get a javascript error:  Syntax error Line 36 Char 1.
Unfortunately the javascript is being loaded dynamically so this doesn't help me.

Here is my implementation code for the TinyMCE editor:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#InputStuffHere').tinymce({
        // General options
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,inlinepopups,preview,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,hr,removeformat",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,image,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,spellchecker",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

        //initialization callback
        init_instance_callback: "TinyMCEReady",
        add_form_submit_trigger : false

    });
});
```

So... anyone seen anything like this or have any ideas for me?  Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your tinymce work with the non-jquery build of tinymce? If yes, then i advise you to use that one. The jquery tinymce version takes 4-6 times longer when processing editor content, typing, etc...

Comment: Still not working, even with the tinyMCE.init function call rather than loading via jQuery.  Beginning to think it's clashing with some other script on the site.

Comment: looks like you will have to switch off that javascript one by one to see what casues the error

Comment: I just ended up removing unneeded javascript includes and it works.  I never did figure out which one clashed with it, but if I do I'll post that up here for others' reference.  Thanks for the responses.